# Is there any way to create account in MS Exchange Server through API

Tags: java, api, exchange-server

I have a portal web in which people can apply an account for Exchange Server.

I don't know much about Exchange Server but an email server or something like that.

My portal web is built with Java. So, it there any API that I can use in order to create account (and set quota) in a specific Exchange Server from my portal web ?

Thank you

Comment: The primary API for exchange is the EWS2 API created by Microsoft. It doesn't seem to include account or mailbox creation. You can check the API at https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api

Answer (score 1):

In Exchange Server 2013 the mailbox creation(Quota) can be done through powershell commands. The Exchange Server's Admin Center itself uses powershell commands to perform all these tasks. So if you are making a portal to perform these tasks first you connect with the powershell of the exchange server machine and execute commands on that. The commands are available at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj943722(v=exchg.150).aspx.